# How Unit test coverage is actually done?

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, sonarqube

I know the theory of coverage testing but in reality, how is the coverage measurement done by the CC tool? I mean, does it check whether each method has an unit test that tests it? Is line coverage somehow involved in unit tests? All I can find is coverage criteria etc but I simply do not understand how these tools (e.g. Sonar) actually measure the unit test coverage.

Comment: Any particular tool you want to know about? Because tools for D language work a little differently than ones for C++, Java tools work in even different way etc. Usually there is some code instrumentation, but it might be done on different levels.

Comment: @TomaszLewowski One tool is mentioned both in the question body and the question tags. So, probably. :)

Comment: @bzlm Sonar is not a code coverage tool, it's more of an extendible quality measurement tool. It uses different tools for different languages (and may be configured to use multiple tools for single language), so I think my question is reasonable ;)

Comment: SonarQube does have a good coverage metrics reporting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coverage is a measurement of how many lines/blocks/arcs of your code are executed while the automated tests are running.

The basic idea behind code coverage is straightforward. During product development, a large number of test cases are created and run to ferret out bugs in the system. Code coverage analysis monitors which parts of the product's code are exercised by the collection of test cases. If there are segments of product code that are never run during testing, then the product has not been thoroughly tested.

So, if you have 90% code coverage than it means there is 10% of code that is not covered under tests. I know you might be thinking that 90% of the code is covered but you have to look from a different angle. What is stopping you to get 100% code coverage??? Just remember, having "100% code-coverage" doesn't mean everything is tested completely - while it means every line of code is tested, it doesn't mean they are tested under every possible scenario.

With Sonar you can monitor the overall coverage of an application and send percentage metrices as per requirement. To get the code coverage by integration tests on your project, you should simply follow the 5 steps below:

1. Attach and configure a JaCoCo agent to the JVM which you will run your integration tests with.
2. Run your automated or manual integration tests within this JVM. At the end of the execution, JaCoCo will dump the code coverage report in the destination you have set in step 1.
3. Configure Sonar to reuse this JaCoCo report. In your project properties file (or directly in the command line), add the sonar.jacoco.itReportPath property with the path to the JaCoCo IT coverage report as a value. You can download an example and look at the projects/code-coverage/it directory: for each launcher you will find a sample.
4. Run an analysis to feed Sonar with the information provided by the JaCoCo report.
5. Browse the results on the Sonar web interface. In the sonar dashboard you can see the classes with lowest coverages and plan your strategy accordingly.

Comment: THanks. But will I know the method coverage? With SonarQube.

Comment: sonarqube does not have method coverage as of yet. you can try bullseye for this.